# Profile picture not displaying correctly in chat

Tags: bug, chat, profile-picture

If you visit [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32541587#32541587) link, you'll see that my thumbnail is broken. I have tried different images and changed to identicon, waited a bit and then back. Still same thing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you upload your own image? Or do you use gravatar? Becaue the latter has issues

Comment: I did it through Edit Profile -> Change your picture -> Upload a new picture. Tried different image sizes and file extensions.

Comment: It's working now :o What happened? Who did something!? This is not something I did, since I've had this issue for many months.

Comment: With enough waffles the unicorns do magic things ..

Comment: @JakobMillah http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @DanNeely Probably, but had persistent issue for months so that's pretty long caching in that case ;o Anyway, it's working now and I'm happy! :)